# JVM Debugger Memory View for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I can't see the "Java Profiling" options in my IntelliJ (see screenshots) and I am not able to launch my Java Spring app with any profiler.
I'm on MAcOS Big Sur, running this version:

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-203.6682.168, built on December 29, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.63 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.16
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1979M
Cores: 12
Registry: compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running=true, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.mallowigi, Docker, GrepConsole, org.jetbrains.kotlin

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Profiling tools are Ultimate only feature: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cpu-profiler.html